# Oracle 11g converts timestamp assuming time is Cental when it already is UTC

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My company recently upgraded to Oracle 11g.  I have a field - Timestamp with Time Zone that has data inserted in as "UTC".  We query the data, make some changes and run a generic update statement that updates all the fields in the table.  Since the 11g upgrade, the update statement converts the date/time assuming it's US/Central (my time zome).   Example:

7/4/2015 7:40:04.000000 AM +00:00 turns into 7/4/2015 12:40:04.000000 AM +00:00 with an update statement like this:

```
Update Tablename 
set FIELD_TIMESTAMP = to_timestamp('07/04/2015 7:40:04 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') at time zone 'UTC'
where ID = 201924;
```

I have tried just inserting a basic date, I have tried using different variations of the time zone.  Nothing works, it always converts the timestamp.

How can I indicate to Oracle that the timestamp I'm updating is UTC and not US/Central time zone so it doesn't convert it?

Comment: I don't fully follow your question. Can you explain what you mean by: "Nothing works, it always converts the timestamp. "

Comment: Are you sure that the update is the problem?  Maybe the update works as expected, but there is something in the way that you ***read*** the value afterwards that performs the timezone conversion.

Comment: I'm looking at the data record in the database using Golden and SQL Devloper.  I don't want the date/time converted when the update is run.  The date being updated isn't Central time zone, it is UTC time already.

Comment: you need to add the timezone to the to_timestamp, not to its result I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using to_timestamp_tz.  For example:

```
SQL> create table tz_test
(
id number, 
col1 timestamp with time zone
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into tz_test values (1, systimestamp)
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tz_test values (2, to_timestamp('20150716 7:40:04', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'))
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tz_test values (3, to_timestamp_tz('20150716 7:40:04 -0:00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'))
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select * from tz_test

        ID COL1                               
---------- -----------------------------------
         1 7/16/2015 1:29:47.031650 PM -04:00 
         2 7/16/2015 7:40:04.000000 AM -04:00 
         3 7/16/2015 7:40:04.000000 AM +00:00 

3 rows selected.
```

My timezone is eastern (-4 from UTC), but the 3rd insert I specify the timezone to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind this issue is that the TZ variable is not set properly in your.bash_profile.

As of now I am almost certain you database will be returning the systimestamp in central

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

In order to permanently fix (like you had prior to upgrade to Oracle 11g) you need to add or edit TZ variable to UTC. For instance if I want to change my timezone to Asia/Calcutta then I have to add/edit the TZ variable like mentioned below

```
TZ='Asia/Calcutta'; EXPORT TZ
```

Once you edit the .bash_profile you need to restart the listener service and database.

Or as an alternative you use can to_timestamp() and to_timestamp_tz() function as suggested by **tbone** to resolve this .

Regards
Andy